Nuance between なくて and ないで
I do not quite get the nuance between the two, as for example
まだ仕事に慣れなくて大変です
まだ仕事に慣れないで大変です
If someone has a good approach to this one I will be happy to hear.
Thank you!

Does this answer your question? ないで vs なくて: combining phrases with negative verbs
